# How do I only allow whole numbers in C?

Tags: c

So i am absolutely new to coding. I tried to code an beverage dispencer and the following code is a part of it in which the user selects the beverage. I am trying to eliminate potential user misinputs such as entering letters or decimal numbers where they are not allowed. I tried a few "solutions" which I read online, but they did not work for me.
Does anyone has an idea?

```
int sortenwahl(){
    
    int puffer, choice, abfang;
    

    do{
        scanf("%d,%d", &choice, &puffer);
            
        switch(choice) {
                
            case 1: printf("\nCola kostet 1€\n"); choice = 1; break;
            case 2: printf("\nWasser kostet 0,50€\n"); choice = 2; break;
            case 3: printf("\nBier kostet 2€\n"); choice = 3; break;
            default: printf("\nSie haben keine verfügbare Wahl getroffen!\nGeben Sie eine gültige Eingabe ein: "); choice = 0; break;
        }
        
    }while(choice<=0);
    
    return (choice);
}
```

Comment: `if (scanf("%d,%d", &choice, &puffer) != 2) { fprintf(stderr, "bad input\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: Read whole line, find out whether it matches the needed syntax, if not read again. Also, never use scanf() without checking the return value.

Comment: [`strtol()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) is what you are looking for (in conjunction with `fgets()`).  It's very difficult to use correctly, however; here you have some code that uses it handling every corner case: https://github.com/alejandro-colomar/libalx/blob/master/src/base/stdlib/strto/strtoi_s.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the return value of `scanf` to figure out if a number has been read. But that alone is not enough. Once `scanf` sees something that doesn't match a number, it exits, leaving that character in the buffer. So further calls to `scanf` will keep repeating the same thing. You need to flush these other characters before you can read a new number. Something like the following should do it:

```
int sortenwahl(){
    
    int puffer, choice = 0, abfang;

    do{
        if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)
            scanf("%*[^\r\n]");

        switch(choice) {
                
            case 1: printf("\nCola kostet 1€\n"); choice = 1; break;
            case 2: printf("\nWasser kostet 0,50€\n"); choice = 2; break;
            case 3: printf("\nBier kostet 2€\n"); choice = 3; break;
            default: printf("\nSie haben keine verfügbare Wahl getroffen!\nGeben Sie eine gültige Eingabe ein: "); choice = 0; break;
        }
        
    }while(choice<=0);
    
    return (choice);
}
```

I would also urge you to read [this excellent article](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) on why `scanf()` may not be the best fit in this sort of situations.

Comment: Thanks for our help!
But can you please explain what ```scanf("%*[^\r\n]"); ``` does in english :) .

Comment: @WladislawKusnezow It reads and ignores characters characters from the stream until it meets an EOL character. That way the next time we try to read a number, these other characters don't come in the way. A detailed explanation is available in the article that I have linked in the answer. This "%[ ]" notation is effectively a more configurable version of the "%s" that we usually use to read a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the return value of `scanf`: As written in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), it returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned or `EOF` if an error occurs during reading:

```c
do {
    int ret = scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (ret == EOF) {
        printf("I/O-Fehler beim Einlesen");
        return -1;
    } else if (ret != 1) {
        printf("Sie haben keine verfügbare Wahl getroffen!");
        continue;
    }

    // switch-statement on choice
} while (1);
```